# How to import grafana dashboard json file manually

Tags: grafana-api

I have exported the dashboard in json format.

I want to import the json file manually to create the same dashboard in new grafana instance.

While googling i got some related information but finding difficulties to implement successfully.

From the site [Grafana API link](https://grafana.com/docs/http_api/dashboard/) i got the code snippet like,

> POST /api/dashboards/db HTTP/1.1
>   Accept: application/json
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   Authorization: Bearer eyJrIjoiT0tTcG1pUlY2RnVKZTFVaDFsNFZXdE9ZWmNrMkZYbk
>
> {
>   “dashboard”: {
>   “id”: null,
>   “uid”: null,
>   “title”: “Production Overview”,
>   “tags”: [ “templated” ],
>   “timezone”: “browser”,
>   “schemaVersion”: 16,
>   “version”: 0
>   },
>   “folderId”: 0,
>   “overwrite”: false
>   }

The above code snippet looks like we can create new dashboard with existing json file but i have no idea of how to implement this code snippet successfully.

Somebody guide me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two techniques to copy the current dashboard -
if you want to export this

1. Go to Current Grafana Dashboard
2. Select the Share button on the top [image]
3. Select the Export Button and Copy the JSON or save it as JSON [image]

Create new Grafana dashboard and copy this JSON model to

- Click on the Setting button on the top
- Click on JSON Model - from left panel  [image]
- Paste the JSON & Save the dashboard and run

Please let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for the response, I have exported the json file as like you mentioned above, Now i need to import the saved json file in my new grafana instance through HTTP API or command line as per the requirement

Comment: kindly assist how to import saved json file through HTTP API

Comment: I am looking to update the grafana dashboard something like this 'curl --user admin:admin "http://localhost:3000/api/dashboards/db" -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" --data-binary @c:/Users/Myname/Desktop/Dashboard.json
'

Comment: tell me exactly what you want, it's simple to just similar dashboard launch in a different instance with copy and pastes the json.

Answer (score 1):

I found and answer to your question - how to import a dashboard in grafana by api - in this post on the community board of Grafana:

https://community.grafana.com/t/how-create-dashboard-and-panel-via-api/10947

Haven't tried this out yet though (we are planning on doing something like this as well).

I will quote the original question in this post:

> Hi All,
>
> I know how to create a dashboard via API but I don’t find instructions to how to create panels within that dashboard still via API. Any idea?
>   the part of the message that explains the answer:

And the response that contains the answer to the question:

> The panels need to be defined within the JSON that you submit in your POST request.
>   The example in the docs doesn’t spell this out, beyond
>   dashboard – The complete dashboard model
>
> To get hands-on with this, you can (1) create a new dashboard with some panels manually, (2) export that dashboard’s definition as JSON, (3) put the exported dashboard definition inside the “dashboard” field of a new JSON object, (4) POST the resulting JSON object to the API endpoint. This will create a copy of your original dashboard. From there on, you can edit the JSON model you’re posting in order to modify or add any panels you desire.
>
> So to your original question, if you want to add a panel to an existing dashboard you can obtain its definition via the API, add the panel to the JSON object, and push the updated model. (keep the same id/uid and set "overwrite": true)"

Answer (score 1):

Note that (now?) grafana has a nice import function too:

[image]